# Deserializing xml containing multiple lists with the same wrapper name in Java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm trying to deserialize xml like this:

```
<MyClass>
  <array>
    <ItemA>...</ItemA>
    <ItemA>...</ItemA>
     ...
  </array>
  <array>
    <ItemB>...</ItemB>
    <ItemB>...</ItemB>
  </array>
</MyClass>
```

to a Java object with two lists (using Jackson-dataformat-xml):

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "MyClass")
public class MyClass {

  private List<ItemA> itemAs;
  private List<ItemB> itemBs;

  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "array")
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localname = "ItemA")
  public List<ItemA> getItemAs() {
    return this.itemAs
  }

  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "array")
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localname = "ItemB")
  public List<ItemB> getItemBs() {
    return this.itemBs;
  }

  //setters ...
}
```

The serializing seems ok but when I deserialize the xml, jackson doesn't seem to be able to parse it, it throws:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Duplicate property 'array' for [simple type, class org.example.MyClass]
```

I've also tried JaxB, which won't throw exceptions during parsing, but the lists in the result are empty.

I know the xml format don't seem to make sense, but is there any chance that I can parse the lists by their item names or their order?

Comment: In the XML there's no guarantee that one of the `<array>`s doesn't contain an element of the other type, i.e. `<array><ItemA/><ItemB/></array>`. How is Jackson supposed to cope with that? Or that you have several `<array>` objects (more than two).

Comment: Supposing that the items are correctly placed, is there any other tool that can solve this? Or maybe there's only handling the Dom directly that I can do?

Comment: I would name them differently :-). You could try creating a custom deserializer, e.g. with `StdDeserializer<MyClass>`. Although you add it using `@JsonDeserialize`, it will be used for XML too. I couldn't get it to work locally, however.

Comment: I wish I could change it but we are the down stream system lol, I will try the custom deserializer though. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Perhaps if you make `ItemA` and `ItemB` implement the same interface, `Item`? You may need a deserializer to determine which one to construct based on the field name or there may be another Jackson-native way of doing it. You'd have to validate at run-time that one array is all As and the other is all Bs.